# What happened to the 'Emoji for English Words' add-on dictionary?

Tags: keyboard, 6.0-marshmallow, gboard, emoticons

On my Nexus 5 running Lollipop, google keyboard had an add-on dictionary that would suggest emoji in the suggestion box along the top when you swiped a word. I recently upgraded to a 6P with Marshmallow and this dictionary isn't in the list of add-on dictionaries. Was it removed or am I missing something? Is there another way to get this functionality in Google Keyboard? I would prefer to stick to Google's keyboard rather than using a third-party app.